# CNAME domain to another domain, but keep different SPF records for the two?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, cname-record, spf

SCENARIO:

- **mydomain.com** is the main website, we do send/receive mail using
  address@mydomain.com. mydomain.com DNS has got an SPF record `"v=spf1 a mx ~all"`
- **mydomain.net** is just an alias for mydomain.com, but we do NOT send mail
  using address@mydomain.net. Therefor mydomain.net DNS has got an SPF record
  `"v=spf1 -all"` to acknowledge everyone it does not send mail

Since mydomain.net is an alias for mydomain.com I wanted to use CNAME in DNS, thus:

```
mydomain.net -> CNAME -> mydomain.com
www.mydomain.net -> CNAME -> mydomain.com
```

But by doing this I noticed that when testing SPF for mydomain.net [with a DNS tool like this](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html) the SPF returned is the one in mydomain.com `"v=spf1 a mx ~all"` and NOT as I would expect the `"v=spf1 -all"`

Is there a way to use different SPF for the two domains, by still using CNAME

Comment: You can't CNAME a whole domain like that.... Are you using some control panel software?

Comment: @Chris S: I'm using cPanel/WHM, and both domains have been added to the server. They work perfectly. When someone enters mydomain.net/www.mydomain.net it goes to mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com. I thought to use CNAME in mydomain.net DNS because I wanted to avoid writing again the IP for each A record. But obviously there is something that I'm missing. about the CNAME, could you explain? Thanks

Comment: use a DNAME if you can, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A CNAME means that the hostname is exactly the same as the target hostname with respect to **all** record types. If this is not what you want then you can't use a CNAME.

You also shouldn't CNAME the root of a domain (i.e. mydomain.net), because this means that the SOA for mydomain.net is actually that of mydomain.com.

Comment: It's an invalid configuration to CNAME a domain at the delegated name server; it would have to be CNAME'd at the root server level, and they don't allow that.

Comment: @ChrisS That's what I meant in the second paragraph.

Comment: I know you know what you're talking about... just spelling it out for the less informed.

Comment: @mgorven: I think I almost got the point. What altrenatives do we have then to avoid rewriting same server IP hundereds of times in the DNS of each domain? See http://serverfault.com/questions/481500/many-domains-sites-hosted-on-same-server-cname-alternatives-to-avoid-writing-sa

Comment: @MarcoDemaio There isn't if you want different SPF records. If you want both domains to be exactly the same you can use a DNAME record however.

Answer (score 2):

From a pure DNS point of view (i.e. don't know about cPanel), you can use a DNAME record to in mydomain.net to redirect to mydomain.com.

In that case, queries for SPF will return the entry both in the corresponding domain but other entries will be aliased:

```
# zone file mydomain.net
mydomain.net. DNAME mydomain.com.
mydomain.net. SPF   "mydomain.net's SPF"

# zone file mydomain.com
mydomain.com. SPF   "mydomain.com's SPF"
someip   A      10.0.0.1

# dig mydomain.net spf
mydomain.net. SPF "mydomain.net's SPF"

# dig mydomain.com spf
mydomain.com. SPF "mydomain.com's SPF"

# dig someip.mydomain.net
someip.mydomain.com A 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: The SPF RRtype record is obsolete. The TXT RRtype should be used for all SPF records.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel isn't actually using a  CNAME; that would be an invalid configuration. I'm not sure how DNS servers would respond to it, but I suspect it just plain wouldn't work. BIND certainly has a tendency to refuse invalid data outright.

What has almost certainly happened is that the cPanel software setup a copy of all the records from the original domain in the second domain. Which would certainly "override" your SPF record.