# Is it valid to have SPF records for a domain that is a CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, spf

I [read](https://serverfault.com/a/481273/38366) that it's not valid to have a CNAME for a domain that also has its own SPF, because all records are taken from the domain that the CNAME points to.

However, this doesn't seem to be what happens for me. I have `pi.dantup.com` CNAMEd to `dantuppi.dynv6.net`, however my SPF record seems to work fine (there is no SPF on the `dynv6.net` domain:

https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/pi.dantup.com
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/pi.dantup.com

This seems to work fine testing with [this tool](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html). However, a friend has his set up very similarly and it appears to not be working. Before digging into this, I'm trying to understand if what mine is doing is correct?

Comment: No, your setup is broken. It may only seem to work because of nonconformant DNS servers or resolvers, but conformant ones will never see your SPF record.

Comment: Bummer :( Google seems to have no problem with it (it shows my emails as spf passes), so I guess it must be the DNS server that's bad and resolvers just work with it

Comment: Danny, I don't think that's the case, try testing by sending an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` and `check-auth@verifier.port25.com` - Every SPF tester I looked at the code for never references the CNAME value.

Comment: @henry Well this is in the headers of an email I sent to Gmail: `Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of danny@pi.dantup.com designates 90.212.60.159 as permitted sender) client-ip=90.212.60.159;` ?! `pi.dantup.com` is a cname. Both cname and txt appear here: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#ANY/pi.dantup.com

Comment: That's fine, that's just an ANY query in DNS - Which returns all records. Where your port25 and mailtest results pass as well? If so you got nothing  to worry about

Comment: @henry It definitely works for me, but we're struggling to get it working for a friend and trying to figure out whether it's correct that mine is working. The post I linked says that CNAMEs will cause the TXT to be ignored (and looked for on the target domain)? :/

Comment: Has your friend sent an email to those two places I mentioned above?

Comment: It's complicated because we don't have a mail relay and are only delivering to to our own Google accounts (directly to their MX server). He contacted his DNS provider who said the TXTs didn't work because of the CNAME. We've worked around this, but still a little confused why it works so well for me (both at the DNS server and Google honouring it!) :)

Answer (score 3):

The discussion you refer to describes CNAME-ing a TLD (top-level domain) to another domain. That is not a good idea.

But CNAME-ing a subdomain over to a third party is actually preferred setup to arrange, for example, bounce-handling by a third party (marketing tools and such).
For example for sending newsletters via the subdomain of `newsletters.example.com` by a marketing tool hosted at `newsmailers.org`, you can use a CNAME record that points `newsletters.example.com` to `example_com.newsmailers.org`, actively delegating the responsibility for SPF and MX records for the `newsletters.example.com` subdomain to the external party.
You cannot, however, add additional RRs (TXT / MX / A) with the same name to DNS, according to RFC 1912.

RFC 1034 section 3.6 states that the RDATA for a CNAME contains a domain name (typically where an SPF TXT record lives), while the RDATA for an MX or NS record should contain a Host Name.

Also, be carefull with CNAMEs that point to other CNAMEs. This will (most often) fail. See RFC 1912 section 2.4

If you take a look at the following article by DMARCIAN, I hope you'll find more details and information you were looking for:

https://dmarcian.com/how-to-send-dmarc-compliant-email-on-behalf-of-others/

If you want to see what's happening on DNS, just check:
https://dns.google.com/query?name=pi.dantup.com&type=TXT&dnssec=true

If you set up a CNAME, you'll first see an answer of type 5 (CNAME) and a second answer of type 16 (TXT).

Comment: This is flatly wrong.  The CNAME [precludes](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain) *reliable* use of any other RRs at the node, notwithstanding any web interfaces' ideas to the contrary.

Comment: I believe we agree that we should not use CNAMEs at the root of a domain. I also believ that we agree we should not use a TXT record with the same host name as a CNAME record. But still I believe it is fine to

Comment: But still I believe it is fine to set a CNAME for pi.dantup.com targeting dantuppi.dynv6.net and dantuppi.dynv6.net being a TXT record.
This is the exact way that AmazonSES, SendGrid, Office365 and many others do delegation of DKIM records.
The article you mention is all about CNAMEs at the apex of a domain, is it not?

Comment: This is why we frown on link-only answers: unless I read your link I can't understand what you're suggesting.  Now you've made it concrete, which is good (though better if you edited it into your answer).  If you edit your answer so that it uses the links as support rather than part of the content, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new to this site.
I've updated my answer and I hope it includes enough information on the topic to make clear what I meant. If you have any other pointers, I'll be glad to incorporate them into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no concern on recursive searches (take into account SPF manages 10 MAX) you can have a redirect SPF, which in my opinion is better than CNAME as SPF is essentially a TXT record on the root of the domain, a CNAME might break you and cause issues when creating other TXT records on the root like verification records which everyone seems to be using now

You can implement this SPF on the root
"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.mailhostbox.com".

Where _spf.mailhostbox.com is your redirected location

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is called SPF Chaining - see here:
[https://www.mailgun.com/blog/white-labeling-dns-records-your-customers-tips-tricks/#:~:text=White%20labeling%20SPF%20records%20SPF%20stands%20for%20Sender,sender%20address%20spoofing%20by%20verifying%20sender%20IP%20addresses](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/white-labeling-dns-records-your-customers-tips-tricks/#:%7E:text=White%20labeling%20SPF%20records%20SPF%20stands%20for%20Sender,sender%20address%20spoofing%20by%20verifying%20sender%20IP%20addresses).